# Select File in mobile browser (Chrome) pushes <body> up

Tags: android, html, css

The application I'm writing has a image upload function. 
When I open the webpage on my android phone, and I want to select an image, the file selector actually "pushes" up all the content in the body.

If you'd like you can visit the website at https://sjbuysse.github.io/sessions-map/, but you'll have to login with your google or facebook account to use it. 
The code is available at https://github.com/sjbuysse/sessions-map

Does anybody understand what's going on over here? Why is that file selector pushing up all the content in the html body?

I posted some screenshots below so you can see what it looks like.

Thanks for any insights.

**Before opening the file selector**

[image]

**While file selector is open**

[image]

**After file selector is closed again**

[image]

Comment: Have you tested this in other Android browsers?

Comment: Just checked it with firefox, and this has the same issue. The first browser was chrome by the way.